# Good general log reader?

Tags: logging

I am looking for a good general log reader that is able to allow users an easy way to extract data from logs.

I am logging to plain text files with columns seperated by tab characters.

Essentially I would like an app that can open log files (no more than 10MB per file) and let the viewer perform some level of filtration, for example date range or column value...

Ideally an open source product. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS? 7 more

Comment: Windows Based, Win Server 2008, Win 7 Clients connected via network share....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splunk (www.splunk.com) is the bomb.  Forget simple filtration, you get a simple Google-like search interface with all kinds of advanced features under the covers if you want them.  It's not open source but it's free for up to 500 MB/day of logs processed.  It can consume just about anything, off disk or you cn set up forwarding agents.

We pull all the apache access/error, tomcat, windows event logs, etc. from many servers into it and use it for querying, reporting, etc.

Comment: Going to test it right now!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07) is the do-it-all tool for log file analysis. No GUI though, but its SQL-like syntax for handling just about any type of input (even multi-file inputs) is tough to beat. And it is really fast.

Comment: Sounds good for extremely large logs...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a desktop app, sever-side app or web based app?

You may be able to find some web apps over at www.hotscripts.com.

For a window app, check out popular file sites like www.brothersoft.com for "field processing" or even excel add-ins if the row counts are reasonable.